# How can I add characters to a string after each iteration of for loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a loading bar for my batch file. The problem is, since my computer is slow, if I keep doing this:

```
set 1=^| & set 2=^| & REM So on so forth
```

Then my batch file will be too heavy for my computer. I think I can use a FOR /L loop, but I don't know how to use it in a FOR /L loop. Thanks for showing some light to the darkness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to build a progress bar. Just setting variables doesn't help you.
You need a way to print a char to the screen (preferably without a NewLine).

There is a trick to do this:

```
<nul set /p "=|"
```

which prints a `|`, but no linefeed

Put a `for /l` loop around (and add some waiting, or it will be too fast to see the desired effect):

```
@echo off
for /l %%a in (1,1,20) do (
  <nul set /p "=|"
  timeout 1 >nul
)
```